# How to skip autogenerated classes from Javadoc using gradle

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-2, javadoc

In an Android library project I use Gradle script to generate Javadocs:

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Exec, dependsOn: buildJavadocsClasspath) {
  doFirst {

    executable = 'javadoc'

    args = [
        '-classpath', javadocsClasspath,
        '-sourcepath', './src/main/java',
        '-subpackages', 'com.example.myproject',
        '-d', javadocsDestinationDir,
        '-exclude', 'com.example.myproject.internal',
        '-doctitle', project.getName() + " " + VERSION_NAME + " API",
        '-windowtitle', POM_NAME + " API",
        '-link', "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/",
        '-Xdoclint:none',
        '-quiet'
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is that Javadoc returns warnings (Java 8) or errors (Java 11) when generating javadocs for classes that reference autogenerated classes like BuildConfig or DaggerMyClientComponent

```
./src/main/java/com/example/myproject/MyClient.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.myproject.internal.DaggerMyClientComponent;
                                              ^
  symbol:   class DaggerMyClientComponent
  location: package com.example.myproject.internal
./src/main/java/com/example/myproject/internal/storage/client/SdkVersionStorage.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.myproject.BuildConfig;
                                     ^
  symbol:   class BuildConfig
  location: package com.example.myproject
./src/main/java/com/example/myproject/internal/utils/UserAgentHeader.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.myproject.BuildConfig;
                                     ^
  symbol:   class BuildConfig
  location: package com.example.myproject
```

One thing that I don't understand is that two errors come from internal classes that are already excluded from javadoc with the "exclude" argument.

On top of that, I don't see an option to fix or suppress those errors. Adding an exclude rule like `com.example.myproject.internal.DaggerMyClientComponent` doesn't work.

Using Android Studio to generate Javadocs is not an option, I need to use a script that can be used in CI (Bitrise).

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I am suffering the exact same problem. Receiving errors due to excluding my internal package

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways of solving this:

**Option 1**

Adding `--ignore-source-errors` to the javadoc command (I took this approach from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63683772/980387))

For the ones using the javadoc gradle task they can add it this way:

```
options.addBooleanOption('-ignore-source-errors', true)
```

**Option 2**

Or adding to the sourcepath the path to your BuildConfig.java file (in case you want to document it)

For the ones using the javadoc gradle task add it to the *source* attribute:

```
source = android.sourceSets.main.java.source + file('build/generated/source/buildConfig/release/your/package/BuildConfig.java').path
```